# How do I know when a DrawerLayout using a RecyclerView is fully populated?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-recyclerview, drawerlayout

I'm making a Material Design [Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html) that gets it's content from a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Recycler.html). Following the [Material Design guidelines](http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html), I'm marking the selected item with special highlighting and to make sure the drawer get's the correct item highlighted I set the highlighting in my activity's [onResume()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume()) method.

My problem is that this only works sometimes. Usually when I start the app it works, but if I kill the app by swiping it out from the Android recent apps list and then start it again it doesn't work.

In this scenario onResume() is called before any content has been added to my RecyclerView so I fail to highlight anything.

How can I know when my RecyclerView has been completely initialized? Alternatively is there some other method than onResume() I can use that is called when the drawer and the RecyclerView is guaranteed to be ready?

Comment: Presumably, your `RecyclerView` items are not empty. You are binding model data to them. When you do that, *also* "bind" your activated state or whatever you are using for your highlighting.

Comment: Thanks! Setting the correct state when binding makes perfect sense, not sure how I failed to think of that. Works like a charm and made the code much simpler as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, when initializing an `AdapterView` or `RecyclerView`, you want your adapter to pull the configuration for the items, rather than trying to figure out the timing of pushing configuration in. Not only does this avoid timing issues, but you usually need that code anyway to deal with stuff like item recycling.

In the case of `RecyclerView` and some equivalent of `ListView's` "choice mode", have the `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` pull in the checked state when it gets the model data to populate the item. Then, the `ViewHolder` can do whatever it needs to do to reflect that state: update a `CompoundButton`, call `setActivated()`, etc.

[This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/RecyclerView/ChoiceList) demonstrates this in the context of a classic checklist structure implemented using `RecyclerView`, and [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/RecyclerView/ActivatedList) demonstrates this using the activated state instead of `CheckBox` widgets.